# Apache POI SXSSF with XSSF constructor, how to edit a row of XSSF template workbook

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf, sxssf

Please assist me with the below issue

I am working with a requirement where I am using SXSSF Workbook for writing a huge excel.

Firstly I have a template workbook which has the header row and cellstyles so I read this first using XSSF as below :

```
XSSFWorkbook workbookXSSF = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
```

Now I am creating a SXSSF Workbook from the above XSSF Workbook as below.

```
SXSSFWorkbook workbookSXSSF = new SXSSFWorkbook(workbookXSSF , 100);
```

I am able to write, rest of the data successfully to this sheet. (sheet = workbookSXSSF.getSheetAt(0))
However I want to protect the entire sheet but want to enable the filters on the header row.
The header row was part of workbookXSSF.
Is there a way to protect the whole SXSSF sheet but enable filters on the header row.

Comment: Not clear where the problem is. For enabling auto filter while sheet protection you set `SXSSFSheet.lockAutoFilter` to `false` before `SXSSFSheet.protectSheet`.

Comment: Thank you @AxelRichter. This works for me.

Comment: this should be written as an answer, so it can be accepted.